# Optimizing away function calls

Tags: c++, optimization

Is it a conceivable that a C++ compiler would optimize out a function call to a class member function that only sets class variables? Example:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int foo;
    public:
        void bar(int foo_in)
        {
             foo = foo_in;
        }
}
```

So if I did this

```
A test;
A.bar(5);
```

could a compiler optimize this to directly access the member and set it like so?

Comment: Turn on optimizations and look at the produced assembly. Chances are if one of the more modern major compilers does, the others will also.

Comment: It can, and you can even hint you strongly want it to by adding an "inline" specifier to the method, if it doesn't already have it by default as in your example.

Comment: @chris Interestingly, I did that by making one member function to set the variable and one to get it, then I set it and did `cout << [get member]` and it optimized it to just `cout << 5`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is called inlining.

Moreover `c++` is designed specifically to support, or make it easier for the compiler to perform, such optimizations in quite complex inheritance cases and templates.

Some would say this is quite distinctive feat of `c++` as a high level language compared to others. Its "high level" features (mostly I mean generic programming - templates) were designed with such optimizations in mind. It is also one of the reasons that makes it considered as efficient in terms of performance.

This is also why would I expect a decent job at working out `inline`s with any reputable compiler.

From what I've read, this is also the reason why it is hard to get all the fancy stuff of other high-level languages such as Reflection mechanism, or other known from e.g. Java or python. It is because `c++` is designed to easily allow to inline pretty much everything possible, so it's hard to introspect optimized code.

**Edit:**

Because you said you are writing an OpenGL stuff where performance of setters and getter and such optimizations do matter I decided to elaborate a bit and show a bit more interesting example where you can rely on inline mechanism.

You can write some interfaces avoiding the `virtual` mechanism but using templates. E.g:

```
//This is a stripped down interface for matrices for physical objects
//that have Hamiltonian and you can apply external field and temperature to it
template< class Object >
class Iface {
protected:  
    Object& t;

public:
  Iface(Object& obj) : t(obj) {};

  Vector get_eigen_vals() {return t.get_eigen_vals(); };
  Matrix get_eigen_vectors() {return t.get_eigen_vectors(); };

  void set_H(VectorD vect) { t.set_H(vect); };
  void set_temp(double temp)   {t.set_temp(temp);};
};
```

If you declare interface like this, you can wrap an object with this interface object, and pass instance of this interface class to your functions/algorithms, and still have everything inlined because it works on the reference of `Object`. Good compiler optimizes whole `Iface` out.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about inlining but I wasn't sure if it would do it automatically in these cases. That's pretty cool that it does because I'm currently writing a program that uses classes with lots of functions like that (just getting or setting variables), and it is good performance-wise that it won't go through the whole function call process.

Comment: @mebob Functions that are defined directly in the function are implicitly `inline`, so you can expect the compiler to make a certain effort to generate them inline.

Comment: @mebob I would not be extremely concerned with this type of optimization on a modern system unless you have functions are expected to be called 10s of thousands of times or more it will not make much of a difference.

Comment: @drescherjm Well I would expect setters (the exact example OP made) and getters to be very important to be inlined, and fitting into the characteristics.

Comment: @drescherjm I agree that it is usually negligible but I'm writing a 3D program using OpenGL and will be constantly accessing classes that hold transformation matrices and such every frame.

Comment: @JamesKanze Isn't the reason that they are "inlined" more for reasons related to the fact that, you would get into trouble with multiple copies of the same symbol in translation unit (I messed up the exact names here probably), not for the performance. I believe if you wrote function complicated enough, compiler would wrap it and elude the inline.

Comment: @mebob Fully understood. I have done similar in the past (being involved in medical imaging for my entire career).

Comment: @luk32 The reason they are inlined is that the compiler decided to inline them.  The reason that they are inline functions (which the compiler should take as a strong hint that they should be inlined) is because the standard says so.

Comment: @luk32 just saw your edit. It's awesome how powerful compilers are, I knew about some of the optimizations that they could do but these just impressive.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question a little bit more generally than just inlining:

There is something in the standard known as the as-if rule. It says that the compiler is allowed to make any change to your program as long as it doesn't affect the observable behaviour. There are even exemptions that allow them to change things that technically do change the observable behaviour.

It can elide function calls and even complete classes. It can do basically whatever it wants as long as it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compiler can optimize this call away.
This is, actually very simple case of inlining.
The compiler is allowed to do much more tan that (it can unfold loops, optimize out local variables replace calculations with constants etc.)